# How to push a map in array and clear the original map to store more data

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am using one map to store name and number as K,V pair. I am using a for loop to run and store multiple data sets in this map. The expected behavior is a loop that will be executed and values will be stored in the map, then I want to push this map into an array and clear the original map to store another data set. My problem is when I try to clear the original map it wipes the data that has been saved in an array as well. 
I tried using deep copy but it is not working. Is there any other way to do it?

Below is my code.

```
for (let GUId of GUIIds) {
          if (GUId.toLowerCase() != parentGUI.toLowerCase()) {
            await browser.driver.switchTo().window(GUId);

            for (let j = 0; j < (await this.elePanels.count()); j++) {
              if (j != 0) await this.elePanels.get(j).click();

              let name = await this.elePanels
                .get(j)
                .getWebElement()
                .findElement(By.xpath(".//mat-panel-title"))
                .getText();

              let number = await this.elePanels
                .get(j)
                .getWebElement()
                .findElement(
                  By.xpath(
                    ".//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']//following-sibling::span"
                  )
                )
                .getText();
              await map.set(name, number);
            }
            await actualData.push(map);
            await map.clear();
            await browser.driver.close();
            await browser.driver.switchTo().window(parentGUI);
          } 

          return actualData;
```

Comment: Probably there is something wrong with your deep copy approach?

Comment: @Robin i  tried something like let copy = {...map}, and cleared the original one , but it still affected the cloned one.

Comment: Looks like your are still using thee same map objects, if you clear them out, everything gets removed. If it's an option, a quick way to test is to use something like: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`. If that works, you need to properly deep clone.

Answer (score 1):

Array is a reference type in Javascript and when a variable is assigned to it, it points to the reference of the array, not the value. You are getting this error because `actualData` stores the reference of `map` array not the value.
To fix this, use `array.slice()` because `array.slice()` returns the value of the array and not a reference.

```
    const actualData = [];
    ...
    actualData.push(map.slice(0))
```

You can read more about it [here](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)